# removing unity after switching from kde plasma

Tags: unity, kubuntu

I installed ubuntu server core and installed kubuntu-desktop afterward. eventually i wanted to switch to gnome as i figured it would be snappier on my system than KDE plasma. however, gnome desktop itself did not install. it seems somehow its apps got installed while unity got installed as the desktop env. I'm not sure how that happened, but now i can't get rid of the endlessly useless unity. i've examined all installed packages through apt and cannot find any packages relating to unity. i have reinstalled kubuntu-desktop package after previously removing it. i also removed all the gnome packages i could find. nevertheless, when i start the x window env it still boots to the unity desktop. could someone please help me figure out how to remove it? thank you!